# Get 403: Request did not include the secret token error in heroku webhook

Tags: python, heroku, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I ran into a webhook problem. I wrote a telegram bot and connected the webhook heroku, also I specified secret_token, which was generated during creation, but in webhook sectio I get an error 403 and says that 403: Request did not include the secret token, please tell me what could be the problem and how to fix it

Code snippet:

```py
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))
WEBHOOK_SECRET = os.environ["WEBHOOK_SECRET"]
...
application.run_webhook(
listen="0.0.0.0",
port=PORT,
secret_token=WEBHOOK_SECRET,
webhook_url='https://<app_name>.herokuapp.com/'
)
```